# mysql one-to-many anti join query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, one-to-many

Looking for help with a query for this situation:

I have 3 tables. Shoe table is a unique collection of shoe models. Color table is a unique collection of colors a shoe could have. shoe_color table is a join table. One shoe model can have multiple colors or just one.

I am wanting to query shoe models that do not contain a particular color. As an example ... `Shoe 1` has the colors `black`, `red`, `white`. `Shoe 2` has the colors `black`, `white`. `Shoe 3` has the colors `black`, `white`. The query for doesn't contain the color `red` should return the rows: `Shoe 2` and `Shoe 3`.

Any help is appreciated and please ask any questions for clarification!

Comment: Use `WHERE NOT EXISTS()` and a subquery that looks for any rows in the join table that join with the current shoe model and the specified row in the colors table.

Comment: thank you! this got me there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not exists`.

Assuming that the join table refers to the other tables through their primary key (say `color_id` and `shoe_id`), and that column `color_name` in table `color` stores the color name, you would go:

```
select s.*
from shoe s
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from shoe_color sc 
    inner join color c on c.color_id = sc.color_id
    where sc.shoe_id = s.shoe_id and c.color_name = 'red'
)
```

Comment: this works great ... I ended up with the same query using @Barmar's comment above. But this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!